# pandoc-include-code force line break at page-witdh

Tags: markdown, pandoc, pdflatex

I want to create a pdf with pandoc and include-code with some code included but if the code is longer than a pagesize it doesnt make a linebreak in the code. So the code is not showing up correctly.

I did some research at the git page from include-code but could not find any explenation how to do this.

This is my command in the Markdown file:

```
{.m include=../ibv_klassifikation/binarizePictureArray.m .numberLines}
```

This is the build command to convert to pdf:

```
pandoc --filter pandoc-include-code from=markdown --output=text.pdf  text.md \ --template template
```

I want to force a linebreak when the code is longer than my pagesize but dont know how to do this with pandoc-include-code

Comment: I expect that this is not a supported feature. Wrapping code is complicated, especially with complex indentation (consider Python where the indentation is part of the syntax). Therefore, you will need to manually wrap your code blocks before feeding your documents to Pandoc.

Comment: you could add something in the LaTeX template or using `header-includes`... e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116572/33952

Comment: That example shows how to get it working with `listings`. Unfortunately `listings` can only break lines at spaces and not break up words. So if you have very long variable names you're out of luck.